# Getting order by order id in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.4

I have custom controller that knows order id, is it possible to get order by order id in custom controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this:

```
    $orderId = $_GET['orderId'];
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $order->load($orderId);
```